# Is it valid behavior of Hibernate (JPQL Query , OneToMany)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I have two entities let say A and B , mapped as below:

```
public class A{
   ...
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   Set<B> bs
}

public class B{
   ...
   String someProp;
   ...
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
   A a
}
```

Some entity instance of A has two elements of B in a database.

When I execute simple query for A like:

```
 entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.id = 1").getSingleResult();
```

and everything works as expected , I got A instance with two instances of B in the Set, but when I executed query:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM A a JOIN FETCH a.bs b WHERE b.someProp= :somePropParam");
query.setParameter("somePropParam","somePropValue");
query.getResultList();
```

I got instance of A with one element of B in the set (element I ask for).

I modified query:

```
 entityManager.createQuery("SELECT b.a FROM B b JOIN b.a a WHERE b.someProp = :somePropParam.. more a conditions );
//.... this query works.
```

Shouldn't first query load all instances of B ? Shouldn't Hibernate execute additional query to load them all ?

Comment: If the A that is returned (by any query that has A as the return type) really has 2 elements in its collection then when you access the collection field of the returned object you should _always_ find 2 elements.

Comment: I think it should return 2 element in "bs" set of A, but it returns just one, as It was returned by  select ` /** columns from a and b **/ 
 from A a inner join A b on a.id=b.a_id 
 where b.someProp='someProperty'` There is no additional query to load additional B table row, that does NOT fulfill condition `b.someProp='someProperty'`

Comment: It might be "expected behaviour" in Hibernate but certainly isn't in other implementations ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected behaviour. This is a common pitfall. The method getSingleResult returns the first row. If there's more than one B of course the result set contains more than one entry, but you only get the first. This might seem a bit odd.

But see it as a plain Query with setMaxResult(1) and a classic sql join. It would end up with the same result. Thats also the reason why hibernate uses subselects for child relations if you use eager fetching.

If you expect a large amount of child data request the childs with an extra query and avoid 1:n bi-directional mappings. A relation from the parent to the child should have a good reason, since it can often lead to problems in the long run.

Additional example consider the following. 
You use your query and setMaxResult(10). The potential result set size to guarantee that you get 10 entries of the parent is unlimited. So hibernate would not have any chance to request the correct amount of data. This can lead to fetching a huge amount of data without needing it.

Answer (score 1):

SQL generated for :

```
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM A a JOIN     FETCH a.bs b WHERE b.someProp= :somePropParam");
    query.setParameter("somePropParam","somePropValue");
    query.getResultList();
```

is as follow:

```
 select  /** columns from a and b **/ 
 from A a inner join A b on a.id=b.a_id 
 where b.someProp='someProperty'
```

It's correct SQL result according to condition (1 row returned) IT tells me "Yes there is one instance of A fulfiling the condition you get, here you are", but I thought that having " JOIN FETCH a.bs" I force Hiberante to load all "bs" collection eagerly even if elements are not returned by the first query. I thought  Hibernate execute additional query like

SELECT b.* FROM B b WHERE b.a_id = (id returned by the query above).

to build complete collection of Bs in A.

Comment: It ought to. It doesn't